# WSO2 EI 6.5 - Name or service not known | DefaultAddressPicker [LOCAL] [wso2.ei.domain] [3.5.4] integrator Name or service not known

Tags: kubernetes, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

WSO2 EI-6.5 is setup in k8s environment. It worked fine without any issue. But due to some reason now it crashing with the below exception. `[EI-Core] ERROR - DefaultAddressPicker [LOCAL] [wso2.ei.domain] [3.5.4] integrator: Name or service not known`

Full Log:

> [2019-09-06 05:07:38,292] [EI-Core]  INFO - JMSListener JMS listener
>   started [2019-09-06 05:07:38,293] [EI-Core]  INFO -
>   PassThroughHttpListener Starting Pass-through HTTP Listener...
>   [2019-09-06 05:07:38,305] [EI-Core]  INFO -
>   PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTP Listener
>   started on 0.0.0.0:8280 [2019-09-06 05:07:38,305] [EI-Core]  INFO -
>   PassThroughHttpSSLListener Starting Pass-through HTTPS Listener...
>   [2019-09-06 05:07:38,311] [EI-Core]  INFO -
>   PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTPS Listener
>   started on 0.0.0.0:8243 [2019-09-06 05:07:38,311] [EI-Core]  INFO -
>   RabbitMQListener RABBITMQ listener started [2019-09-06 05:07:38,320]
>   [EI-Core]  INFO - HazelcastClusteringAgent Cluster domain:
>   wso2.ei.domain [2019-09-06 05:07:38,320] [EI-Core]  INFO -
>   HazelcastClusteringAgent Loading hazelcast configuration from axis2
>   clustering configuration [2019-09-06 05:07:38,336] [EI-Core]  INFO -
>   HazelcastClusteringAgent Using kubernetes based membership management
>   scheme [2019-09-06 05:07:38,352] [EI-Core]  INFO -
>   KubernetesMembershipScheme Initializing kubernetes membership
>   scheme... [2019-09-06 05:07:38,353] [EI-Core]  INFO -
>   ApiBasedPodIpResolver Parameter KUBERNETES_API_SERVER not found,
>   checking KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST & KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS
>   [2019-09-06 05:07:38,354] [EI-Core]  INFO - ApiBasedPodIpResolver
>   Kubernetes clustering configuration: [api-server]
>   https://10.233.0.1:443 [namespace] wso2 [services]
>   wso2ei-integrator-service [skip-master-ssl-verification] true
>   [2019-09-06 05:07:38,565] [EI-Core]  INFO - ApiBasedPodIpResolver
>   Reading IP addresses from endpoints [2019-09-06 05:07:38,565]
>   [EI-Core]  INFO - KubernetesMembershipScheme Member added to cluster
>   configuration: [container-ip] 10.233.64.189 [2019-09-06 05:07:38,565]
>   [EI-Core]  INFO - KubernetesMembershipScheme Kubernetes membership
>   scheme initialized successfully [2019-09-06 05:07:38,567] [EI-Core] 
>   INFO - HazelcastClusteringAgent Hazelcast cluster is initializing...
>   [2019-09-06 05:07:38,625] [EI-Core] ERROR - DefaultAddressPicker
>   [LOCAL] [wso2.ei.domain] [3.5.4] integrator: Name or service not known
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: integrator: Name or service not known
>     at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
>     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)  at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)  at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1077)     at
>   com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker.getPublicAddress(DefaultAddressPicker.java:289)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker.pickAddress(DefaultAddressPicker.java:124)
>     at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.(Node.java:143)    at
>   com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:152)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:135)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:111)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent.init(HazelcastClusteringAgent.java:196)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.enableClustering(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:293)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.completeInitialization(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:187)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.serviceChanged(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:317)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.registerThrottlingAgent(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:123)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.activate(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:100)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:515)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:220)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:105)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1230)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1066)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5433)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5731)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [2019-09-06 05:07:38,627]
>   [EI-Core] ERROR - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Cannot initialize
>   cluster com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: integrator: Name or service not known
>     at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil.rethrow(ExceptionUtil.java:67)
>     at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.(Node.java:145)    at
>   com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:152)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:135)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:111)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent.init(HazelcastClusteringAgent.java:196)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.enableClustering(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:293)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.completeInitialization(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:187)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.serviceChanged(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:317)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.registerThrottlingAgent(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:123)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.activate(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:100)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:515)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:220)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:105)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1230)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1066)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5433)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5731)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: integrator: Name or service not known
>     at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
>     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)

Answer (score 1):

You can get this resolved by adding an /etc/host entry to the container. So in K8s you can update the pod template in Deployment as follows.

> ```
> spec:
>   hostAliases:
>     - ip: "127.0.0.1"
>       hostnames:
>         - "integrator"
> ```